# What does concatenating '\b' to std::string exactly do?

Tags: c++, backspace

I am very curious. What behavior does concatenating `\b` do to an `std::string`?

Will it simply add the `'\b'` to the end of the string, or do `pop_back`, and is this behavior defined? Although I can test it, I cannot do this experiment on every platform.

Some additional questions are if it just concatenated the backspace to the string,  does this comparison return true or false?

```cpp
std::string foo = "asdf\b";
std::string bar = "asd";
if(foo == bar)
```

Edit: I was pretty sure that it just concatenates the `'\b'` but I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: The same behavior as concatenating any other character. One character is no different than any other character. "`\b`" is just a character, just like "`0`" or "`!`".

Comment: Escaped characters are characters like any other, there's no kind of run-time interpretation of character values. With ASCII encoding, appending `'\b'` to a `std::string` object just adds the `char` integer value `8` to the string.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it exhibits zero prior research.

Comment: I did search through docs and stuff, and I was pretty sure that it would just concatenate the backspace. I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: @user207421 That's only a suggetion, i'm not endeavoring to stop it. Ignore it if my guss is wrong :/

Comment: I tried it on visual studio. The behavior was concatenation of backspace. However, I don’t currently have a easy way of getting Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or do pop_back?

it won't, regardless which platform you are using.

> does this comparison return true or false?

False.

because `'\b'` is also as an ASCII character as are all the others.

C++ won't make any guess on the function of the characters, for they are only integers, nothing special. The function of `'\b'` is processed by other programs, they don't remove any element in the string.

```
[cling]$ #include <string>
[cling]$ std::string a = "abcd"
(std::string &) "abcd"
[cling]$ std::string b = "abcde\b"
(std::string &) "abcde\x08"
[cling]$ a == b
(bool) false
```

Comment: Yeah, I was pretty sure that was the answer. I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Re: "because `'\b'` is ... an ASCII character as are all the others" -- maybe; but there are systems that don't use ASCII, and nothing in this question depends on being ASCII. In C and C++ `'\b'` is a backspace character; the compiler produces a value for it that works as a backspace in whatever encoding the compiler is targeting.